# ASP.NET dynamic changing of master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

Is it possible to change the master-page of a content-page with the click of a button on that content-page?

If not why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible, you'll have to override the OnPreInit method of your codebehind class like so...

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    Page.MasterPageFile = "~/your/masterpage.master";
}
```

So to bind this to a click, you could use a query string parameter, i.e.

```
<a href="<%=Request.Url.ToString()%>?masterPage=alternative">Use
alternative master page</a>
```

And then in the codebehind

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if(Request["masterPage"] == "alternative")
    { Page.MasterPageFile = "~/your/alternative/masterpage.master"; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the master page programmatically, however you can only do it in the pre-init event.

http://odetocode.com/articles/450.aspx

Comment: But how can be a button related to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a regular, non-server `<form>`, with a hidden `<input>` field.  When the form posts, you check for the `<input>` value in the `Pre_Init` event, and change the Master Page there.

You can't use a server-side form with a regular button event, because they fire too late in the page life cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I did this recently where I changed an image on the masterpage based on the page that was being rendered.

1) I referenced the control (imgPageSpecificTextImg on the Masterpage)

2) Changed the URL that the code was pointing to.

```
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgText = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)Master.FindControl("imgPageSpecificTextImg");
            imgText.ImageUrl = "images/banner.jpg";
```